# Does the proof of productivity of connectedness require Axiom of Choice?

Tags: general-topology

For arbitrary index set $\Lambda$, the product space
$$ X = \prod_{\alpha \in \Lambda} X_{\alpha} $$
with product topology is connected if all of each $X_{\alpha}$ is connected.

In the standard proof of this fact, one first fix an element $a \in X $ and set up for finite subset $I$ of index set $\Lambda$ a connected set
$$X_I = \{ x \in X | x(\alpha) = a(\alpha) \; \forall \alpha \in X-I \} $$
and takes $X^{\infty} = \cup_{I \subset \Lambda} X_I $ and prove that closure of $X^{\infty}$ is $X$

I think that the pickup of $a$ in $X$ at the outset requires Axiom of Choice, but none of materials I have consulted with give any comment on that matter. Am I right in that the productivity of connectedness (in product topology) requires Axiom of Choice?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To even be sure that the product of non-empty sets is itself non-empty requires AC, so you are correct.

Comment: That direction doesn't need the axiom of choice: if you can't choose an $a$ in the product, the product is empty, hence connected. If one has any qualms about using the axiom of choice, one would have to mention it, "either the product is empty, hence connected, or we can pick an $a\in X$, and ...".

Comment: @DanielFischer Ahh, good point.